# Powerbook compiler queries

Tags: java, macos

I am thinking about buying an Apple Powerbook 1.5 GHz machine. While my primary focus for that machine would be internet, I may also do some programming on that machine since it would be the machine I would be taking to college...
What I wanted to know if there would be any major difference in context with the compilers used etc? Would I have to setup a completely different environment for the Power PC?

To be fairly clear, my primary categories of work include:
* Python {i know mac supports this right out of the box}
* PHP/MySQL
* HTML/CSS
* Javascript
* Java - I will be starting to learn Java, do this is pretty significant.

I am a complete n00b as far as Mac OS is concerned. Any and every help is appreciated.

PS: If this falls in the wrong category, I apologise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that, with the latest recent release of OS X, 10.6 or Snow Leopard, Apple has pulled the plug on Power PC Macs: 10.6 does not run on any PPC Mac.  Based on its past support policies, you can expect that Apple will continue to provide security updates and, possibly some bug fixes and minor features, for 10.5 (Leopard) until the next release of OS X (as yet, unannounced).  But you can also expect that more and more things will be released by Apple or third-parties that are Intel-only, like the things already mentioned.  Of the list you mentioned, it would seem that the only immediate concern is Java 1.6; Python and the rest will be no problem for a long-time to come.

By the way, you might want to check out [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/), two independent projects that tailor and package for OS X hundreds of popular open source packages.  If it isn't already shipped with OS X or you need a newer version, you may find something you need there.

Answer (score 2):

The Powerbook can't do Java 1.6.  That might be a problem for you.  You also can't do iPhone development on it.  Other than that, once it's maxed out on RAM it's a pretty decent development environment.

Answer (score 2):

I own a MacBook (intel core 2 duo processor) myself and would strongly discourage you to get an older model than that if you want to get reasonably up-to-date java support. (Java 1.6 does *not* work on older models as far as I know) I really like my macbook and it is a great development machine for me, but I have strong doubts on the java support (See for example http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2007/10/28/os-x-java-definitive-timeline/).

Answer (score 0):

I have an 12" 1.5 Ghz, 1.25GB ram G4 Powerbook and I wouldn't recommend it for java development due to the fact that running an IDE (Eclipse or NetBeans) will be painfully slow. Also expect to buy a new battery for an old laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If 10.5 is not enough for you, you may want to consider installing Linux since the StuffIt you mention is easy to install with e.g. Ubuntu.

Comment: While PPC versions of Ubuntu have existed in my experience I would not consider it a "usable" operating system on a PPC Mac.